# Proof of a complicated complex inequality involving reciprocals of sums.

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

Assume that $X_1 ,\ldots ,X_n ,\alpha$ are complex numbers with $\operatorname{Im}(\alpha )>0$. How can I prove the following inequality? $$\left| \frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{X_j +\alpha}}\right|^2 \leq \frac{1}{\operatorname{Im}(\alpha)^2}\frac{1}{\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{|X_j +\alpha |^2 }\right)^2}.$$

**My try:** By the triangle inequality we have: $$\left| \frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{X_j +\alpha}}\right|= \frac{1}{\left|\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{X_j +\alpha}\right|}\geq\frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{|X_j +\alpha|}}.$$ Then we have: $$\left| \frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{X_j +\alpha}}\right|^2 \geq \left( \frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{|X_j +\alpha|}}\right)^2 .$$

But now I don't know where $\operatorname{Im}(\alpha)$ come from. I'd really appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: The parentheses on the right seem to be misplaced. Do you mean $\Big| \frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{X_j +\alpha}}\Big|^2 \leq\frac{1}{Im(\alpha)^2}\frac{1}{\Big(\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{|X_j+\alpha |^2 }\Big)^2}$ ?

Comment: I doubt that this inequality holds without any restriction on the complex numbers $X_j$.

Comment: Dear @MartinR ,Thanks for the comments. This inequality comes from the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.06110.pdf the inequlity before relation (3.4). Please see (3.1) also.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with all that notation and stuff. But unless I am mistaken, you can always find complex numbers $X_1, X_2$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^{2}\frac{1}{X_j +\alpha}$ is zero (or arbitrarily close to zero), but $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{|X_j +\alpha|} \ne 0.$ Then the left-hand side of your inequality becomes arbitrarily larger, but the right-hand side is bounded.

Comment: @MartinR It's OK. That's right. So I need to review the paper maybe these is any restriction on the complex numbers $X_j$. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: And for $n=1$ the inequality holds only if $\operatorname{Im}(\alpha)^2 \le 1$.